# PytorchLightning calls training_epoch_end before all steps of epoch were completed. always at about 0.25 size of steps

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I'm new to pytorch_lightning, my training is going well but for some reason training_epoch_end is called after some steps and not at the end of epoch.

these are my outputs:

GPU available: False, used: False

TPU available: None, using: 0 TPU cores

Validation sanity check:   0%|          | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

| Name                | Type                 | Params

---

---

Epoch 0:   0%|          | 0/13 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Epoch 0:  23%|██▎       | 3/13 [01:38<05:27, 32.75s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

//training_epoch_end: outputs = [{'loss': tensor(6.4593)}, {'loss': tensor(5.7653)}, {'loss': tensor(1.9642)}]

Validating: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]

Validating:   0%|          | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Epoch 0:  38%|███▊      | 5/13 [01:48<02:54, 21.78s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 0:  46%|████▌     | 6/13 [01:59<02:19, 19.91s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 0:  54%|█████▍    | 7/13 [02:10<01:51, 18.58s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 0:  62%|██████▏   | 8/13 [02:20<01:27, 17.60s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 0:  69%|██████▉   | 9/13 [02:31<01:07, 16.83s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 0:  77%|███████▋  | 10/13 [02:42<00:48, 16.21s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 0:  85%|████████▍ | 11/13 [02:52<00:31, 15.71s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 0:  92%|█████████▏| 12/13 [03:04<00:15, 15.34s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 0: 100%|██████████| 13/13 [03:15<00:00, 15.00s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 0: 100%|██████████| 13/13 [03:16<00:00, 15.15s/it, loss=4.73, v_num=7]

Epoch 1:  23%|██▎       | 3/13 [01:42<05:42, 34.24s/it, loss=3.39, v_num=7]

//training_epoch_end: outputs = [{'loss': tensor(2.6766)}, {'loss': tensor(2.3010)}, {'loss': tensor(1.1722)}]

Epoch 1:  31%|███       | 4/13 [01:48<04:04, 27.22s/it, loss=3.39, v_num=7]

Validating: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]

Epoch 1:  38%|███▊      | 5/13 [02:02<03:15, 24.42s/it, loss=3.39, v_num=7]

Completed 6.8 MiB/327.9 MiB (48.7 KiB/s) with 2 file(s) remaining

Epoch 1: 100%|██████████| 13/13 [03:48<00:00, 17.54s/it, loss=3.39, v_num=7]

Epoch 2:  23%|██▎       | 3/13 [01:44<05:47, 34.72s/it, loss=2.72, v_num=7]

//training_epoch_end: outputs = [{'loss': tensor(1.2504)}, {'loss': tensor(1.4905)}, {'loss': tensor(1.4158)}]

Epoch 2:  31%|███       | 4/13 [01:49<04:07, 27.48s/it, loss=2.72, v_num=7]

Validating: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]

Epoch 2: 100%|██████████| 13/13 [03:50<00:00, 17.75s/it, loss=2.72, v_num=7]

Epoch 3:  23%|██▎       | 3/13 [01:43<05:46, 34.62s/it, loss=2.27, v_num=7]

training_epoch_end: 3  outputs = [{'loss': tensor(0.6632)}, {'loss': tensor(0.9215)}, {'loss': tensor(1.1396)}]

Epoch 3:  31%|███       | 4/13 [01:49<04:06, 27.41s/it, loss=2.27, v_num=7]

Validating: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]

does any one know why this happens ?

number of workers or gpus does not affect the order.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

o.k that was totaly my bad!

I was confused by the epoch 0..13 printouts and didnt understand that only three of them were training and the rest were validation.